# Alterar Senha do root do mysql no linux!

Tags: mysql, linux, senhas

Boa tarde Pessoal!

Sou novo no mundo do desenvolvimento e tbm sou novo em linux. Eu instalei o mysql client e server e depois instalei mysql-workbanch via central de programas do xubuntu. Em momento nenhum ele me pediu para configurar a senha e eu não consigo conectar pois não sei a senha do root. 
Eu tentei senhas padrões e tentei não "por" senha vazia, ele acusa access denied. 
Procurei por tutoriais na internet, vou colocar um aqui de exemplo onde eu segui os passos, "https://www.secnet.com.br/blog/alterar-senha-root-mysql-server", e meu terminal me apresenta o seguinte erro no momento do seguinte comando "# mysqld --skip-grant-tables &":

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

eu não sei como fazer, eu já tentei diversos tutoriais mas não estou conseguindo acessar. Por favor podem me ajudar?

Comment: qual distribuição você utiliza do linux? quais senhas padrões você tentou? tentou root, toor, deixar o campo vazio?

Comment: Esse erro colocado no post não tem nada a ver com senha, simplesmente não foi localizada instância de DB rodando com a mesma config do client. Seria importante você [edit] o post, e descrever com mais exatidão o problema. Se o post linkado acima não resolver, acrescente os detalhes conforme sugerido, que se o problema for realmente diferente e dentro do escopo do site, a pergunta pode ser reaberta.

Comment: Amigo, a melhor maneira é sempre consultando a documentação. O MySQL tem uma ferramenta que pode alterar a senha do root (dentre outras funcionalidades). É o mysql_secure_instalation. Você tem que rodar com o root (sudo). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html